# Lambda Expression - C# compiler inference

Tags: c#, expression-trees, type-inference

I am trying to understand compiler inference behavior. For example from below code snippet, run time type of compiled delegate is `Func<int>`

```
Expression addExpr = Expression.Add(Expression.Constant(2), Expression.Constant(1));
LambdaExpression lambdaExpr1 = Expression.Lambda(addExpr, null);
var compiled = lambdaExpr1.Compile();
```

However below line of code does not compile. Not sure what is ambiguous here for compiler to implicitly convert it into `Expression<Func<int>>` and assign to variable to type LambdaExpression

```
LambdaExpression lambdaExp2 = ()=>2+1;
```

One possible reason i can guess of that lambda expression on right side could also match signature of my custom delegate in which case compiler have no way to infer delegate type. But same reason applicable to my initial code snippet. Why CLR (runtime) can decide that it can be of type `Func<int>`. And if this is possible and close enough inference by runtime then why not c# compiler can also do same.

Comment: `()=>2+1` can either be translated by the compiler to `Func<int>` or `Expression<Func<int>>` and neither can be implicitly casted to `LambdaExpression`

Comment: @haim770: Why can an `Expression<T>` not be implicitly converted to `LambdaExpression`, its base class?

Comment: @EricLippert, I didn't notice it's actually the base class. You're right.

Comment: Accelerated lambda expression compilation and approaching of static type inference here... https://github.com/valerysntx/expressionutil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me begin by re-stating the question in a more concise form.

> A lambda expression can be converted to `Expression<T>` where `T` is a delegate type compatible with the lambda expression. `Expression<T>` is derived from `LambdaExpression`. Why then can we not convert a lambda expression directly to `LambdaExpression`?

The reason is: because this is one of the rare situations in C# where type information flows from the *type of the assignment target* to the *type of the thing being assigned*.  The delegate type must be known by the compiler when converting a lambda; **the C# compiler does not deduce the type of the delegate from the lambda, but rather verifies that the lambda is compatible with the given delegate type**.

Now, could we have designed and implemented a system whereby if the type information was not present, and the conversion target was `LambdaExpression`, then a reasonable guess would be made? Sure. There was nothing stopping us other than no one wanting or needing that feature.

But the answer to the question "why doesn't this feature exist?" is always the same.  **We're not required to give a reason to not implement a feature**. No one asked for that feature, no one designed it, implemented it, tested it, or shipped it to customers.  Therefore, no feature.

Rather, non-existing features require an advocate to kick off making them into existing features. If this is a feature you want or need, then take it up on the github forum and advocate for the feature.  Or implement it yourself; the compiler is open sourced.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are mixing anonymous lambdas and delegates with named ones; consider following declaration:

```
delegate int del();
```

While your expression in first snippet matches signature of this delegate you cannot convert it to this type since `LambdaExpression` returns anonymous type:

```
var mydel = compiled as del; // Returns null
```

On the other hand if you build Expression from typed delegate it will remain the signature even after compiling:

```
Expression<del> exp = () => 2 + 1;
LambdaExpression lambdaExp2 = exp;
var compiled2 = lambdaExp2.Compile();

var mydel2 = compiled2 as del; // This will work
```